# Replace group of symbols with one symbol in R

Tags: regex, r

I have this list `mylist`, I want to remove all the symbols (except '`_`') and replace with '`:`' and get the `result`.

```
 mylist <- list("NP_570602:+", NA_character_, NA_character_, "XP_006719119:-;NR_040112:-")

result

1 NP_570602
2 NA
3 NA
4 XP_006719119:NR_040112
```

Comment: I don't understand.  In the first element you removed the `:` but in the last you kept the middle one and removed the last one.

Comment: @Richard Scriven I am only interested in getting these ("NP_570602", "XP_006719119") items   and if there are multiple then separate them by ':', If there is only one then no need to put ':'.

Comment: I don't want to replace '`_`' as it is the part of identifier I need to use. I just want to remove all other symbols. I don't even have to replace them with '`:`'

Comment: Fyi, `mylist` really should just be a character vector (created with `c()` not `list()`)

Comment: @Frank that is right, I just dput it and pasted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
v[!is.na(v)] <- lapply(strsplit(v[!is.na(v)], "\\W+"), paste, collapse=":")

# [[1]]
# [1] "NP_570602"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "XP_006719119:NR_040112"
```

The `\w` character class is `[a-zA-Z_]`, the characters the OP is interested in. `\W` is its complement.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use list is because I wanted to preserve the level so that I could column bind to their corresponding table in my dataframe.

Comment: @MAPK Ok. I don't really understand, but I've switched to a version that gives a list.